# extract a variable from a string provided by curl

Tags: curl, grep

I am using curl to send a request to a website to perform a search and return some data. The output looks like this:

```
[{"label":"Statham, john smith (2122)","value":"Statham, 
john smith","cat_id":"wew","talking" :"9999990F5ECC8300000000CC","spanner"
:null,"class":"f","id":"9999990F5ECC83000013D5CC"}]
```

Is it possible to extract the data from this as some sort of array so I can call on each varavle as a varable?

For example I would like to end up with a variable for the last field which has a label of "id" and data of "`9999990F5ECC83000013D5CC`"

so when I call $id I get `9999990F5ECC83000013D5CC`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally new answer since you  want a  bash solution.  That requires manually parsing the JSON object, since bash has no builtin to do it.

Here is a quick and dirty modified from https://gist.github.com/cjus/1047794 - I added `| sed 's/\]//'` because the original was leaving the last  bracket in the returned value.  I have not fully analized the regex construction - I find that regex can usually be coded several ways with same results.

```
#!/bin/bash
function jsonval {
    temp=`echo $json | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/\]//' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w $prop`
    echo ${temp##*|}
}

json='[{"label":"Statham, john smith (2122)","value":"Statham, john smith","cat_id":"wew","talking":"9999990F5ECC8300000000CC","spanner":null,"class":"f","id":"9999990F5ECC83000013D5CC"}]'
prop='id'
val=`jsonval`
echo $prop': '$val
```

You will need to modify this to use your curl call to set `json` before calling `jsonval` - my example is runnable as-is to show you it pulls the correct string from the object.

Comment: This worked for me well and was easy to understand. Many thanks. I did fin take a look at jsawk which looks like it could work as expected but I couldn't get it work as well as this sollution on my distribution. Thanks again

Comment: NP :)There are hybrid bash/php solutions around but bash/sed/awk is a classic combination - fast and accurate, if sometimes a little strange looking, mostly due to regex stuff.

Comment: Yes it's better to stick with standard stuff as it's always available. How would we enhance this script to echo out a simple array? Yes I know that's what we started with but I have a larger version of this where I only need to pull out 4 variables out of an entire page of json

Comment: That is complicated enough that I would use a php script to do it as in my original example.

Comment: After using this script for some time I rebuilt my server and now it's broken. What do I need to have installed to run the script? Currently I am using centos 6.6 and php version PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$a` is set equal to your json string,

```
$b = json_decode($a,true);
```

will make `$b` an associative array so that `$b['id']` is the value you want

for more: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: Thanks for the message. This has helped me to understand that the output I am getting from the website is json. How would I use json_decode in a bash script to get the id variable I want? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My [Xidel](http://xidel.sourceforge.net/) can do that.

For example for the `id` variable:

```
eval "$(xidel your-data-source --input-format json --output-format bash -e 'id := $json//id'  )"
```

Multiple variables can be created with `id := $json//id, label := $json//label`, and the data-source can be an url, so you do not even need curl anymore.